# dcc32 Error x.pas(648): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'x'

Tags: delphi, properties, indy

So I've tried to add two properties to  unit IdMessage.pass. So i've added

```
  TIdMessage = class(TIdBaseComponent)
  private
    FTaskID: Integer;
    FNotificationID: Integer;
  protected
   ... all protected properties and procedures


  public

   ... all protected procedures and functions

    property TaskID : Integer read FTaskID write FTaskID;
    property NotificationID : Integer read FNotificationID write FNotificationID;

  published

    ...published properties
  End;
```

The unit looks Ok, but when I try to compile a project that uses these two properties I get the Undeclared identifier error. I have no idea why. If I CTRL+CLICK the property at design time, it takes me to the property in the unit, but when I try to build or compile it runs into this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to rebuild/reinstall Indy's design time packages. Or better yet, extend the `TIdMessage` in your code instead of modifying Indy.

Comment: Check your library and search paths. The compiler probably doesn't use your modified source code but an already compiled unit (dcu).

Comment: @TLama how do I do that?

Comment: Don't do this. Solve your problem without changing Indy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan any particular reason? I'm not changing  anything that was inside the component, I try to store some informations about each e-mail.

Comment: @TOndrej it worked after I readded the path, thank you!

Comment: Don't change the source code of installed components. Every-time when you will update the INDY components your changes will be lost. Inherit the class and add the modifications to your own class.

Comment: Looks like you are changing Indy code. Did you write all the code in IdMessage.pas?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i ment, i'm not changing any writen code, i'm  adding new one.

Comment: @RBA will do so! Didn't thought of that untill now.

Comment: Subclassing might be the right solution but we can't be sure of that since we can't see the problem.

Comment: @CiucaS Actually, yes you are changing existing code. So much as adding a line break in any Indy units is changing Indy's code. But as already said, that code is already compiled elsewhere. When you compile your app, it's using the already compiled DCU's instead of what you've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what you say in the comments, you are modifying third party code. In effect you are making a fork. The compiler error is just the first symptom of the trouble that lies ahead. The compiler is not using the code that you have written. The compiler is using a different version.

For sure you can make the fork work by ensuring that the compiler uses your fork rather than the original code. However, you are setting yourself up for a fall. Next time you upgrade Indy, what will happen? Will you be able to merge your fork into the new Indy?

If forking is the best solution, so be it. But it almost certainly is not. We don't know what your actual problem is but forking seems unlikely to be the best way forward. Try to find a design that allows you not to modify the Indy code.

Comment: I'll do so, it would be easier just to add a property to the current Indy unit, but as you said it's a bad design for future upgades. I'll build a new class with what I want to modify.

Comment: @CiucaS It's not as easy as you may think. Last time I tried to modify Indy (thus requiring me to recompile it), the recompile failed and I was stuck with a broken library. It's much more ideal to inherit this class in your own project and add what you need there.